# Hook into the Windows File Copy API from C++

Tags: c++, windows, hook, c++builder, file-copying

I need to hook copyfile in order to stop the process whenever a malicious file is being copied. I saw a question asked by Cat Man Do

[Hook into the Windows File Copy API from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590155/hook-into-the-windows-file-copy-api-from-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

and he mentioned that there is a solution for this problem in c++. I am using embarcadero c++ builder(non-MFC). Is this solution applicable for c++ builder and if it is can anybody post the link or give me a hint on how to hook copyfile in c++?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing a virus scanner. You need to do this with a filter driver. It may be easier to use one of the recognised virus scanners......

Answer (score 4):

You're not being specific about what you mean by "stop the process" - whether there is a specific process you are interested in, or whether you want to block all file copies throughout the entire system. If you want to block all file copies throughout the system, then what you're looking for is a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540402.aspx). This is extremely advanced, since you will be writing a kernel-mode driver. [Not for the faint of heart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx). Note also that you may end up being flagged as malware yourself, since malware will try to hook the file system in order to hide themselves.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, but I need to be informed whenever a copy operation is made and I am going to scan all files in the source directory and if none of the files are malicious, I would leave it alone otherwise I need to warn the user. SO I do not want to block all file copies throughout the system, only some of them...

Comment: Right, but what is the scope of the hook? If a batch file copies some files, do you need to hook those too? Or only when certain programs copy files? What if the user opens the file in Notepad, then does a Save As? Does that count as a copy?

Comment: well yeah if a batch file copies some files I need to hook that too, but in the case of a notepad, I do not count that as a copy. I need a system wide hook.

Comment: Um, you do realize that all file copying is done the Notepad way. There is no "copy a file" file system primitive. (The CopyFile API internally does reads and writes.)

Comment: Well then that's ok, I find out the process and if it is notepad, I'll ignore it ...

Comment: But you can copy files from Notepad. (Go to the File.Open dialog and drag files around.) And what about Wordpad? Excel? Photoshop? And what algorithm are you going to use for detecting "copy" operations given that they show up in the file system as just "read" and "write"? (I guess you could compare the bytes being written against every file in the source directory, but that may get unwieldy if the source directory is large or changes frequently.)

Comment: Well I need to detect those copy operations too, sorry I thought you were talking about text copying, I need to hook copyfile so that I get informed of every copy operation.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Deviare API hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) to do it. You can use its COM objects to intercept CopyFile and CopyFileEx APIs and prevent the call returning ACCESS DENIED in the last error.